# Whatsapp suspicious message

Tags: whatsapp, scam

Received a message from an unknown individual on WhatsApp messenger. I did not recognize the number (the person is not on my contact list), and there is probably an attachment (4 messages were sent).

I deleted the message and the attachment without tapping to open the message (whatsapp asked whether I wanted to delete the attachment, I chose yes).

I believe the message was from a possible scammer sending a virus embedded in an attachment.

I also uninstalled  and  re-installed WhatsApp messenger.

A virus scan using multiple software on my phone yielded nothing was wrong.

Are there any other steps I should do to be secure?

Is there a way to prevent random messages like this on WhatsApp? (I have blocked this specific sender but I want to prevent such messages in general)

Answer (score 4):

WhatsApp is an open protocol, anyone can message anyone.

Just deleting the message would have been good enough